# Some iTunes features for Linux

Tags: music, music-player, itunes

iTunes lets you "ignore" some tracks (by unticking them) and set the start/end time for each one.
Is there a player, for Linux, that lets you do the same?

Comment: Have you used VLC? It's highly customizable.

Comment: Does it have the two aforementioned features?

Comment: Only one way to find out...